# Forge Viewer toolbar buttons disappearing on small browser

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using forge viewer version v6.4 for the rme_advanced_sample_project sample model. When I resize my Chrome browser to a relative small size (600px in width), I discovered that some of the toolbar buttons are disappeared from the viewer.

When I check the debug console, I can see that those buttons has a CSS property of ***display: "none"*** assigned to them after the resize. When I change the value of those to ***display: "block"*** again, which is the original value before resizing, I am able to see the buttons again.

Attached with some screenshots for your reference:

**Before:**
[image]

**After resizing to a small size (~600px in width):**
[image]

**After setting the css of the buttons:**
[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to disable such behaviour so that all the toolbar buttons will always be shown? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep those buttons visible at all times you can override the `display` setting in your stylesheet like below:

```
#YourViewerDiv #navTools #toolbar-panTool{display:block !important}
//Inspect in browser console and apply the same to the other buttons you'd like to keep visible
```

Alternatively for a programmatic approach, the offending code for this behavior:

```
//GuiViewer.js
this.addEventListener(et.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT, function (event) {

            viewer.resizePanels();

            if (viewer.viewCubeUi && viewer.viewCubeUi.cube)
                viewer.viewCubeUi.cube.refreshCube();

            viewer.updateToolbarButtons(event.width, event.height);
        });
```

So you suppress it in your own listener by always resizeing to a wide enough `width`:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT, ()=>viewer.updateToolbarButtons(1000,1000))
```